# Flutter Element Embedding in 3rd party websites

Tags: flutter

Flutter recently introduced **Element embedding** which allows us to integrate Flutter components within HTML web pages. (see demo here: https://flutter-forward-demos.web.app)

I would like to use this new feature to create a flutter app that can easily be embedded in **3rd party websites**.
However, I could not find a clear documentation or tutorial to do that.

Does anyone here can explains what are the steps to do that? Or does anyone know a good tutorial?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

Found the source code from `flutter/samples`.
[Web Embedding Example](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/web_embedding)
If you want to try this out, you may need switch flutter to master channel.

If you want API documents, you can find it here:
[Master Channel API Doc](https://master-api.flutter.dev)

Comment: They usually publish some articles when feature is released.